# Using Service's ClusterIP Address inside POD

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-classic, kube-proxy, kubernetes-service

I am using Kubernetes Service of type Cluster IP, which will expose a deployment. 
In my container I want to use the Service IP (cluster IP). Is there any way I can get the IP Address inside the Pod/container?

Is it possible to get the cluster IP from Service name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, via the [environment-level service discovery](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services) mechanism. Note, however that any service that you want to access like this must be created **before** the pod itself has been launched, otherwise the environment variables are not populated.

Answer (score 2):

Within the containers/POD, you can use a dns name which refers to the service.
Basically, the file `/etc/hosts` is populated with the kube-dns edress.
You can just use it as like:

```
<svc-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

If you must need the IP, you can use [ENV Variablse](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services) or just ping the DNS name.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the comment below about envs. Sorry about that :) .